# Explain Garbled circuit having function and single input?

Tags: symmetric, multiparty-computation, garbled-circuits

I came across below Image of garbled circuit and want to know what exactly is garbled circuit and if we consider two party computation then how can we differentiate between f and x as Alice and Bob's input and what exactly is f and x.

Also How it can be useful for Multi party computation..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an abstraction of the garbled circuit concept. In multiparty computation, the input $X$ is split between the parties. For example, the first party may hold the first half of $X$ and the second may hold the second part of $X$.

Regarding the function $f$, this is something completely different and defines the structure of the circuit.